# Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement in vb.net using Access database "how can i fix it ?"

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Opretprofil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Opretprofil.Click
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.PakkeAppDatabaseConnectionString)
    If Email.Text = Nothing Or Passwordtillogin.Text = Nothing Or Gentagpassword.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Indtast din Email og dit Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    ElseIf Passwordtillogin.Text <> Gentagpassword.Text Then
        MsgBox("Udfyld venligt alle felter korrekt", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else

        Try
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(Email,Password) Value(?,?)", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Email.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Passwordtillogin.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()

            MsgBox("Profil er nu oprettet", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

the problem i think is in this part:

```vb
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(Email,Password) Value(?,?)", connection)
```

Comment: `VALUES` plural. `Value` is not a correct keyword

Comment: Also, `Password` is a reserved word in Access so must be escaped when used as an identifier, i.e. `[Password]`.

Comment: By the way, I know that names are actually ignored by Access and parameter positions are what matter but why not use sensible names anyway? It makes the intention of the code clearer and thus makes mistakes easier to spot. If you name both your parameters "@1" then it's not obvious if you have then in the right order but if you use "@Email" and "@Password" in both the SQL and when adding them to the command, it's much more obvious if they are in the wrong order or you're using the wrong value.

Comment: You are mixing the syntax of `.AddWithValue` and `.Add` . The first one takes 2 parameters, the Parameter Name and the value of the parameter. The second one takes Parameter Name and OleDbType. Since the second method is the preferred one just change `.AddWithValue` to `.Add`

Answer (score 0):

Is better to identify the parameters and if you want to use AddWithValue you have to give the value :

```
 Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(Email,Password) Value(@Email,@Password)", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",  Passwordtillogin.Text)
```

Hope this help

Comment: Contributor Mary in the comments had a good point about using .Add instead. [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) explain why.